# Websharper and VS 2010 shell

Tags: visual-studio, websharper

Does anyone know how to use Websharper with VS shell?  I understand that the Websharper developers recognise this and intend to add it to future releases ?:  https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/35/support-installing-with-vs-shell-only

In the meantime:  https://bitbucket.org/Mickeysg/websharper/src/1aa9056f55f9/README.markdown

Is it still possible to install and use Websharper with the shell only?  If so are there any downsides to this currently?

> If you have only the free VS shell and F# compiler installed, you'll need to add
>   `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` to your PATH.

```
    PATH=%PATH%;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
    msbuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

`msbuild` without options will build the Debug configuration for platform AnyCPU.

If I am reading the above quote correctly?  If I am could anybody give an "idiots" guide to completing this please?

TIA, Ian

Comment: Disappointing not to get a reply.  I'd like very much to try out Websharper but am not about to buy a VS Pro licence.  (Is it possible to withdraw a question from Stack Overflow?)

Comment: The posting on FPISH has been deleted!!??  Why?

Comment: Must have been a glitch, I think the posting is available now.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion has moved to FPish: http://fpish.net/topic/Some/0/75413